# Is "box-shadow: inset" compatible with "%" specification

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a dynamic shadow in a box. So I could adjust the size boxes without problems with the shadow

```
height:50px;
border-radius:50%;
width:50px;
display:block;
background:#dedede;
box-shadow: inset -10% -30% #cecece;
```

Comment: Tested. Does not work.

Comment: `box-shadow` does not accept percentages regardless of whether you have `inset` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is **NO** -> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

`box-shadow` does not accept percentages